# Truncation Test Series and Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm not sure what this means, can anyone explain it more clearly?

> Suppose that $a_n$ is any sequence. If there is some $n$ for which the series
>
> $$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k$$
>
> converges, then the series corresponding to $a_n$ converges.

Comment: Welcome to SE ! Try to be more specific on what part of the statement you don't understand so people could help you with better accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

If we have, separating the whole sequence into two parts,

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k + \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k
$$

we know that it becomes simply:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k + K.
$$

Finite sequences converge, unless something funky happens with $a_k$ with $0 \leq k \leq n-1$. Think of it as being assured that the long tail will eventually not be a problem, which is usually the part that makes it non-convergent.